# Help on how to find an equation of a plane passing through a line and a point.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

My question is:

> Find an equation for the plane that contains the point $(1, -1, 2)$ and the line $x=t, y=t+1, z=-3+2t$.

Can someone please give me a step-by-step explanation on how to do this? I have tried many ways, but none of them work.

Comment: Welcome to [Math SE!](https://math.stackexchange.com/) . Please read this  [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to begin with and share your thoughts and efforts in the question .

Comment: Look through the handy list of related questions at right. There are at least two questions there about the same sort of problem as this one.

Comment: I know. But none of them seemed to make much sense to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

We can proceed as follows

- take a vector $\vec v$ parallel to the line
- take a vector $\vec w$ form the given point to a point on the line

then a normal vector to the plane is given by

$$\vec n = \vec v \times \vec w$$

Comment: Wow. I solved it! I never tought it would be that simple!

Comment: Sorry, by 'tought' I meant 'thought'.

Comment: @Human Well done! That’s fine. Bye